# AWS SNS Publish message method is not working inside a UNIX server

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, unix, amazon-sns

Below is the program that I am using to publish a message to SNS. There is no issue when I execute this program(simple Java or Spring boot) in my local system. The message is published on the topic.

But, the actual program runs inside a thread in a spring boot project. The thread runs every 1 minute. Whenever the thread runs, the below program has to publish the message. This spring boot project deployed inside a standalone Unix server. From the server, it is not publishing messages. There is no exception. The logs are showing a successful handshake to the Amazon network.

I tried AmazonSNS and SnsClient classes as well.

```
AmazonSNSAsync snsClient1 = AmazonSNSAsyncClient.asyncBuilder()
          .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
              new BasicAWSCredentials("access-key",
                  "secret-key")))
          .withRegion("us-east-1")
          .build();
      log.info("STATUS: snsClient1 formed");
      PublishRequest publishReq =
          new PublishRequest()
              .withTopicArn("sns_topic-arn")
              .withMessage("mes: "+message);
      log.info("STATUS: publishReq formed");
      snsClient1.publishAsync(publishReq);
```

I tried the below things already.

- moved the program out of the thread
- tried with a new topic
- used the latest dependency of SNS

However, when I published a message from the Unix box using AWS CLI, the message was published successfully.

Did anyone face a similar issue? If not, you can share any alternative way to hit the SNS from a Java program if you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is partially fixed. AWS SDK was throwing an error, not an exception. That was the cause of the code block. Once, I catch with the "Throwable" keyword, the program is not stopping.

Later, I used the bom concepts to avoid the transitive dependency version conflicts and converted all the AWS SDK 1 code into SDK 2 code. Now, the message is posted on the SNS topic. But, the weird thing is that SDK2 also throws a similar error. I am trying to fix it.

***Reference:***

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/sns/src/main/java/com/example/sns/PublishTopic.java

Meanwhile, you can track the issue on the below page as well.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/discussions/2867